# Run Nodejs Electron application on tablets

Tags: android, node.js, electron, tablet, windows-10-universal

I'm developing a node.js electron desktop application.

Is it possible to run this application (without consideration for my source code) on tablets with **Windows 10, Android**, or an simliar os?

If this isn't the case, are there os for tablets that are able to run these kind of applications?

I am thankful for all help and information.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do that. That's because node support for mobile is still questionable and if you want to pick more reliable route, you could design view layer to be responsive and reusable as a regular webpage app or even within similar wrappers for mobile, such as cordova/phonegap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The key problem is that the application should by able to run without an internet conection. That could be a problem :-/.
I'll have a look at cordova and/or phonegap.

Comment: You can develop the page to still work in offline mode. Have a look at [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).

Comment: I had a look at cordova and it could be a great alternative! Thanks :-)